# Can't export my image from Google Earth Engine

Tags: image, export, google-earth-engine

I'm aware I'm far from the first person to ask this question, but I found myself likewise perplexed at how to export an image from this godforsaken program, and after trying to parse through a lot of JavaScript that might as well be Greek to me, I've decided I'm in need of an answer specific to my own plight. Below is my code:

```
var aer = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NAIP/DOQQ')
                .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-02-01', '2020-09-04'));
var trueColor = aer.select(["R", 'G', 'B']);
var trueColorVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 255.0,
};

var visual = trueColor.visualize({
  bands: ['R', 'B', 'G'], 
  min: 0, 
  max: 255.0
})

Map.setCenter(-97.43, 42.03, 13)
Map.addLayer(trueColor, trueColorVis, 'True Color');

var TrueColorvis = trueColor.visualize({
  bands: ['R', 'G', 'B'],
  max: 0.4
});

// Create a task that you can launch from the Tasks tab.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: trueColorvis,
  description: "Aerial view of Norfolk",
  scale: 30
  region: geometry
});
```

With 'geometry' being the desired area that I highlighted. I'm constantly faced with the error message:

> Line 11: trueColor.visualize is not a function

And while I'm vaguely aware that this is because my image isn't a 'function,' I'm not sure how to make it one. I'm pressed for time on a final project for a class and really just need to move on to the next step, I really didn't expect this to be the part that sucked away multiple hours of my time.

I'm obviously pretty inexperienced with this program, so if an answer can be provided in a manner that doesn't rely on me having a solid depth of knowledge about this program, that would make a world of difference (exact reason I wasn't able to learn anything from answers to similar questions asked). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `trueColor` is an `ee.ImageCollection` (many images), not `ee.Image` (one image). Only images have `visualize()`.

To fix this, and do the same thing that `Map.addLayer()` does, use `.mosaic()` to combine the images:

```js
var TrueColorvis = trueColor.mosaic().visualize({
    ...
```